# C# is there a foreach oneliner available?

Tags: c#, syntax, foreach

I just want to know if there is a foreach oneliner in C#, like the if oneliner `(exp) ? then : else`.

Comment: I think my answer goes straight to the point you want!

Comment: I don't know if it's what the OP wanted, but @sergiol had what I wanted.  A way to give foreach a set of literals to be used exactly once.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you're dealing with an array then you can use the built-in static [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2.aspx) method:

```
Array.ForEach(yourArray, x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

If you're dealing with a `List<T>` then you can use the built-in [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) instance method:

```
yourList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

There's nothing built-in that'll work against any arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>` sequence, but it's easy enough to roll your own extension method if you feel that you need it:

```
yourSequence.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

// ...

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Odd enough that they don't have this stuff built in. I guess if one would follow the Python pattern, one would use `Select` to build a new enumeration?

Comment: @Domi Answer to why: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Comment: can you tell about Dictionaries too?

Answer (score 7):

`foreach` line-liners could be achieved with LINQ extension methods. For example:

instead of:

```
var result = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in someCollection)
{
    result.Add(item.Title);
}
```

you could:

```
var result = someCollection.Select(x => x.Title).ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

Imagine you have three variables and you want to set the same property of them all in only one go:

```
foreach (var item in new [] {labelA, labelB, labelC})
{
    item.Property= Value;
}
```

It is the equivalent of doing:

```
foreach (var item in new List<SomeType>(){labelA, labelB, labelC})
{
    item.Property= Value;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[List.ForEach Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can use something like `List<>.ForEach`:

```
List<String> s = new List<string>();
s.Add("This");
s.Add("Is");
s.Add("Some");
s.Add("Data");
s.ForEach(_string => Console.WriteLine(_string));
```

Answer (score 1):

The primary difference between `if` and the `?`operator is that `if` is a statement, while `?` produces an expression. I.e. you can do this:

```
var _ = (exp) ? then : else; // ok
```

but not this:

```
var _ = if (exp) { then; } else { else; }; // error
```

So if you are looking for something like a foreach expression, there is no .NET type that can naturally return except for void, but there are no values of void type, so you can equally just write:

```
foreach (var item in collection) process(item);
```

In many functional languages, a Unit type is used instead of `void` which is a type with only one value. You can emulate this in .NET and create your own foreach expression:

```
class Unit
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public static class EnumerableEx
{
    public static Unit ForEach<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Action<TSource> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            action(item);
        }

        return new Unit();
    }
}
```

However there hardly exists any use-case for such expressions.